# rdebug continue past breakpoints

Tags: ruby, rdebug

I have put some `debugger` breakpoints in my rails app within some long loops. After hitting the breakpoint and evaluating what I need, is there a way to continue ignoring the rest of my break points?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it depends on which debugging tool are you using, all you have to do is remove all breakpoints once you have evaluated what you need.
In rdebug, the instruction is

- `del` to disable all breakpoints.
- `del <bp_id>` to disable one concrete breakpoint.

to see the breakpoints ids, just:
 `b`